# Flipped image - only in browser

Tags: html, css, image, browser

When I view the image properties (see below) on my windows machine, it clearly says `width:144` and `height:256`.  But when viewing it in the browser the dimensions are flipped.

Example of it flipped in the browser:
http://jsfiddle.net/pLyg7ug9/2/

Direct link (notice that it loads correctly in chrome):
http://pro-cuts.herokuapp.com/images/slideshow/thumb/8_flipped.jpg

What would cause the browser to flip the width and height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due JPEG Rotation and EXIF Orientation. Basically your camera has a sensor that rotates the image depending on how you take it. Phones that have their orientation locked will have these issues.

[image: JPEG Exif Data]

Comment: Thanks for the info, I had no idea that existed.  Do you know of any way this could be resolved by css, to force the browser to honor the height / width?

Comment: I see that this exists, but unfortunately only in firefox http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-orientation

Comment: @JustinBicknell You could have a bunch of checks to change the rotation depending on the browser. But your best bet would be to just fix where the problem starts, the image itself. You can just open it in an image editing program, rotate it if needed, and re-save it. Or take the pictures with the correct rotation (enable rotation when taking the picture).

Comment: I found a decent way to handle bulk operations this using this tool http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php.  The following command seems to work nicely:  `mogrify -auto-orient *.jpg`